# Derivative of a multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In the book "Multivariate Calculus and Geometry", written by Seán Dieen, it's written the following:

> If $F:U\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ then $F(X)$ has $m$
>   coordinates $f_1(X),\cdots,f_m(X)$ and we often write
>   $F=(f_1,\cdots,f_m)$ where each $f_i$ is a real-valued function on $n$
>   variables. Hence, $F=\sum_{i=1}^mf_ie_i$( $(e_i)_{i=1}^n$ is the
>   canonical base of $\mathbb{R}^m$) and $F$ is differentiable if and
>   only if each $f_i$ is differentiable.

My question is: is $F'(X)=(\nabla f_1(X),\cdots,\nabla f_m(X))$? Since $F'(X)\in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$ this notation is strange, but the author assumes exactly that. I was confused and I am in doubt if this notation is really correct.

Are there any books (preferably from Springer) that explain these details better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F’(X) in this case is the **Jacobian** m-by-n matrix which m rows are the gradient of each component.

Notably we define the *derivative* of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, if it exists, is the unique linear transformation $Df(x) \in L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ such that
$$
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|f(x+h)-f(h)-Df(x)h\|}{\|h\|} = 0
$$

where

$$Df(x)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}&\dots&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}\\\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}&\dots&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_2}&\dots&\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}\\\end{bmatrix}$$